# PLA vs Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Just started getting into machine-learning, and I'm wondering if there is a relationship between the Perceptron learning algorithm and linear regression?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there could be a relationship. You can have data on students' scores (dependent variable, y-axis) and hours of study before an exam (independent variable, x-axis). You could use OLS to generate linear regression line, and then you could use PLA to classify all students above the line as "smart", since they have high scores for how much they studied, and all students below the line as "dumb".